# Function not returning value

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm having trouble getting the value from this function, I'm not sure why but is returning empty. I debug it with firebug and it run two times, the first one return empty and then the second one return the value.

Any idea how I can correct this.

```
function validation() {
    if (val()); {
        alert("Error");
    } else {
        alert("Pass");
    }
}

function val() {
    var answer;
    dojo.xhrGet({
        url: "ValodS?option=12",
        handleAs: "text",
        load: function (response) {
            if (response == 'Pass') {
                answer = false;
            } else {
                answer = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: You can't return the result of an *asynchronous* request from... from a... nevermind.

Comment: Because AJAX calls are asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're returning answer before it is ever being sent (the AJAX request is run in the backround without blocking the calling code.

The easiest solution would be to have the caller pass a callback function to your function. You could then call the callback function inside of the `load` handler (thus passing the data that way).

Comment: Can you give me an example, I,m a little bit confused.

Comment: If it's acceptable to make your GET request synchronously, you could add `sync: true` the object passed to `dojo.xhrGet`. This will allow set your `answer` variable to be set in the request's `load` callback and it will be returned at the end of `val()`. This is most likely not the best approach though for your usage as others have mentioned, an asynchronous request (what you currently have) would work better (but it won't can't `answer` outside of the load callback).

Comment: Which could be  the problem in setting sync to true;

Answer (score 1):

When val returns, `answer` is not assigned. You are calling an asynch operation that sends off a http request. The control flow then continues, and when the http request eventually is finished, the anonymous function you defined, that assigns `answer`, is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra ; after your `if`

Change the first line from

```
if (val());
```

to

```
if (val())
```